# Concatenate data in Image SRC

Tags: vue.js

I am fetching data from an API and then displaying it with a V-FOR.
I get the data and index from this API however i wont be to splice the index and insert that sliced data in the ImG Src attribute .
I am not sure how i can slice and insert that new index into the img src.

Please help

```
<td><img src="https://example.io/us/flat/64.png"></td>
<td><span class="badge badge-primary">{{index.slice(0,2)}}</span></td>
<td>1 {{base}} = {{data}}</td> 
<td>{{time}}</td>
```

Comment: Can you share a full example? How does your data look like, how do you fetch it and what kind of output do you expect

Answer (score 0):

You can set the whole source with vue:

```
<img v-bind:src="'https://example.io/us/flat/' + index.slice(0,2) + '.png'" />
```

or shorter

```
<img :src="'https://example.io/us/flat/' + index.slice(0,2) + '.png'" />
```